# On the topic of Kausalsätze

Tags: sentence-structure, word-order

Here are two sentences from my grammar textbook: 1)"Ich musste zu Fuß nach Hause gehen, weil ich die letzte Straßenbahn verpasst hatte"; 2)"Du musst langsam sprechen, weil der versteht nicht viel". The book states that in the former, "weil" is used to introduce a subordinate clause while in the latter, "weil" is used to introduce a second independent (coordinate) clause. My question is why is that? I thought that any Kausalsatz is a Nebensatz.

Comment: What book is that?

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer**: The second one is *colloquial*, something inbetween main and secondary clause and not a Kausalsatz, it is unclear what *weil* is (Duden uses the term "Operator" for them) and lastly the second *weil* can be used in 3 different ways, while the Kausalsatz-weil only knows one usage: The cause.

---

`1` uses "weil" as a subjunction and `2` uses "weil" as a.. what exactly?.

Whether it is a subjunction or conjunction, Duden is not clear about. At one point, they refer to it as a conjunction ( Randnummer 1696 ), at another, as a >subjunction< (note the characters around it, Randnummer 2017), but also sorting it (and others like *obwohl*) into a speech-only category called **Operators**.
From the positioning, you can call it a conjunction. It is positioned in front of the first part of the clause.

2 is only correct in everyday language (i.e. colloquial language).
In standard German, whether spoken or written, "weil" cannot be used like this - "denn" would be the best alternative for your sentence, as an example.

---

But is `2` independent? And why is it not a Kausalsatz?
**It gets complicated from here on.**

a.  You can only use `2` in post-position to another sentence. Does that mean that it is independent? It's certainly not a main clause, because those can stand alone. **That's why I would say that your book is wrong.**

But it uses a conjunction.. or a subjunction? So... is it a secondary clause or not? From my understanding, this is just not clear. Maybe it is one of the types of sentence which fit in neither category: Neither main, nor secondary. A number of sentences exist with this problem, so it's not unreasonable to assume that.

b. `2` gives the **reason**, which not necessarily has to be the **cause**.

> Der fährt bescheuert, weil er fährt Schlangenlinien.,

In this sentence, no cause was given, just the reason for the observation in the first sentence.
As a third usage, suggestions can also be reasoned for using *weil*

> Wieso machst du nicht den Abwasch, weil die Teller sind dreckig.

This demonstrates how verb-second clause with *weil* can't be called Kausalsatz, which have to include the *cause*.

Also, this is why almost all verb-last clauses with "weil" can be rewritten, but not the other way around.

```
+------------+--------------+-------------+
|            | --usually->  |             |
| Verb-last  |              | Verb-second |
|  (cause)   | <-sometimes- |  (reason)   |
+------------+--------------+-------------+
```

Dudenband 4, Randnummer 1696, 2017, 2021.

Comment: Can you quote one of the Randnummern that make the verb in second position in the *weil*-clause "legal"? All examples sound wrong to me.

Comment: @Raketenolli I put the randnummers at the end. No, I can't legally give you a quote from the book, as that would infringe copyright.

Comment: @Raketenolli Be assured that I've only slightly altered the examples from the book to be safe. The basic meaning and structure is same or similar. The sentences should be both correct. Also keep in mind that these are in spoken language. Have you tried speaking them out loudly? Maybe this will sound better to you.

Comment: It's unclear to me which part of your post comes from the Duden and what is your own writing. `this is programming code` btw, please use some other markup for quotes. --- The OP's example 2 is colloquial, but still wrong (from a more prescriptive than descriptive point of view, because people do speak that way). Your two examples sound weird to me, because *weil* introduces a Nebensatz with verb-last position, and like you said yourself, *weil* describes a cause or reason. *Er fährt Schlangenlinien* is not a cause for *Der fährt bescheuert*. ...

Comment: In your second example, the first part is actually a question, so you'd typically say *Warum machst Du nicht den Abwasch? Die Teller sind dreckig.* (or, if you absolutely need a *weil*: *Ich frag ja nur, weil die Teller dreckig sind.*)

Comment: Yes, it is colloquial.

Comment: As I said in my answer, "weil" is not a cause in "Der fährt bescheuert..." and this is a "proof" for the verb-last "weil" and verb-second "weil" not being interchangeable. Because verb-last "weil" has to always be a cause, while the other one can be a reason that is not the cause. 
This is also visualized with the ASCII-table at the end, and you will find this in Duden 4 at Randnummer 2021.

Comment: @EagleFliesBanana "No, I can't legally give you a quote from the book, as that would infringe copyright." Luckily, this is very wrong! Look up "Zitatrecht" (and the international and US equivalents): https://www.bildung-forschung.digital/digitalezukunft/de/wissen/urheberrecht/urheberrecht-in-der-wissenschaft/gesetzliche-erlaubnis-und-zitatrecht/gesetzliche-erlaubnis-und-zitatrecht.html - Don't let unfounded worries get in the way of your useful contributions here!

Answer (score 1):

The second is actually not "good" (prescriptivist) grammar as it is taught in the grammar books.

It is still very commonly used among native speakers in spoken language. Then it has the same meaning as "denn".

Further reading: [Weil das ist ein Nebensatz](https://bastiansick.de/kolumnen/zwiebelfisch/weil-das-ist-ein-nebensatz/)

Answer (score 1):

Your book is correct. Grammatically speaking, the first «weil» clause is a constituent of the main sentence introduced by a subordinating conjunction, whereas the second «weil» clause is another main sentence linked to the first one by a coordinating conjunction.

The **movement test** proves that the first «weil» clause is a constituent. The «weil» clause can be moved into the «Vorfeld», that is, into the position before the finite verb:

1. Ich musste zu Fuss nach Hause gehen, weil ich die letzte Strassenbahn verpasst hatte.
2. Weil ich die letzte Strassenbahn verpasst hatte, musste ich zu Fuss nach Hause gehen.

A clause that is a constituent of another sentence is a subordinated clause. Conjunctions that introduce such clauses, like «weil» in your first example, are called **subordinating conjunctions.**

The second «weil» clause cannot be moved to the Vorfeld:

3. Du musst langsam sprechen, weil der versteht nicht viel.
4. *Ungrammatical:* * Weil der versteht nicht viel, musst du langsam sprechen.

The **replacement test** shows that in the second «weil» clause, you can use typical coordinating conjunctions instead of the «weil»:

5. Du musst langsam sprechen, (denn|aber|und) der versteht nicht viel.

This means that «weil» in your second example is a **coordinating conjunction.**

Coordinating conjunctions link two clauses of the same order, in this case, main sentences. They add some semantics to the kind of relationship between the two sentences, specifying whether there is causality, contrast, or mere concomitance. But even if the second sentence is in a causal relation to the first one, it would not be called [Kausalsatz](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kausalsatz). Kausalsatz only refers to a subordinated clause that is a causal adverbial in the main sentence it is a constituent of.

Furthermore, conjunctions like «und», «denn», or «aber» are not constituents of the sentences they introduce. If they were constituents, they would occupy the Vorfeld exclusively:

6. *Ungrammatical:* * Du musst langsam sprechen, (denn|aber|und) versteht der nicht viel.

Instead, the Vorfeld is occupied by a regular constituent (in your example, by «der»). Therefore, including the conjunction when looking at the sentence in isolation does not make much sense. The sentence would just be «der versteht nicht viel».

And of course, the use of «weil» as a coordinating conjunction is considered a colloqualism, as the others have already pointed out.

Comment: You recite a lot of basic knowledge but it's unclear how the second clause can be a main clause if it can only be used in post-position of another sentence, and never alone. This does not fit the definition of an independent main clause.

Comment: @EagleFliesBanana: You are mistaking the coordinating conjunction to be a part of the sentence it introduces. It is not, as I have shown. The second sentence is «Der versteht nicht viel», perfectly acceptable as an independent main clause. Just compare a simple example like «er kam und sie ging». The second sentence is «Sie ging», and the coordinating conjunction _und_ just links the two sentences together.

Comment: Ok, I am going to rework my understanding.